# How DNN Platform process a page request?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Please explain various folders and important files in DNN package.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5ALy.png)

Comment: https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/module-development

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself a copy of one of the Wrox books about DNN.  I cut my DNN teeth on the volume with DNN 4 in the title.  Lots of detail regarding the architecture of DNN and (IIRC) the page lifecycle were covered.  It's probably in the later books, but I didn't read them as closely.  The 4 book is probably available for cheap these days.